# String manipulation boolean

Tags: java, string

```
String a ="abc";
return (a.substring(1)=="bc");
```

I tried to print the result of
        a.substring(1) 
which is also
        "bc"

Why the result is false?
I think it's true.

Comment: substring returns new instance of String representing `"bc"` which is different that `"bc"` literal interned in string pool so `==` (reference comparition) returns false

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares references and the value of primitives (`int`, `long` etc), use `a.substring(1).equals("bc")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
String s = "abc";
System.out.println(s.substring(1).equals("bc"));
```